# Display default page in browser address

Tags: .htaccess

Hello I need to display my default index page on web browser when I come to root page on my website.

Example: When I go to `example.com` the browser should display(show) `example.com/myindex`.

My htacess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
DirectoryIndex myindex.php
```

Comment: You mean the `myindex.php` document should be served, but the browser address bar should presumably still show just the bare domain. eg. `example.com`? What problem are you currently having?

Comment: I mean when i connect to `example.com` in the address bar will show `example.com/myindex` i don't know how to explain these more.

Comment: Which file do you want to serve? `myindex.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to *display* `example.com/myindex` in the address bar when you initially request `example.com/`, you need to issue an *external redirect*. So, immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive, try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /myindex [R=302,L]
```

Then, providing you have a file called `myindex.php` that you want to serve, your remaining directives should internally rewrite the request from `/myindex` to `/myindex.php`. (The existing `DirectoryIndex` directive is not necessary in this instance.)

If you need this to be a permanent (301) redirect then change the `302` to `301` when you are sure it's working OK. It is easier to test with 302s since they are not cached by the browser, unlike 301s.